# Как сделать чтобы работал transition при изменении liner-gradient?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть такой код который должен плавно менять цвет

```
setInterval(() => {
   document.getElementById('backgroundLinear').style.background = 'linear-gradient(-90deg, '+ randomColor +' 0, rgba(76, 229, 180, 0))';
   document.getElementById('backgroundLinear').style.transition = '5s';
}, SEC_INTERVAL * 1000);
```

Проблема в том что он меняет цвет но не плавно.
Как выйти из данной ситуации ?

Comment: градиенты не анимируются - придётся искать другое решение

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну если пораскинуть мозгами, то мы генерируем,а списком показываем какие именно нужны градиенты это массив цветов colors: смотрим пример

Как анимировать градиент подсмотрел [здесь](http://www.themesindustry.com/html/mitex/index4.html)

И да забыл написать что у вас там ошибочка...sec interval к примеру и вы должны были сделать функцию и в сет интервале обновлять значения вашей функции ..

в общем Дэмо на лицо

```js
    var colors = new Array(
        [62,35,255],
        [60,255,60],
        [255,35,98],
        [45,175,230],
        [255,0,255],
        [255,128,0]);

    var step = 0;

    var colorIndices = [0,1,2,3];

    var gradientSpeed = 0.002;

    function updateGradient()
    {

        if ( $===undefined ) return;

        var c0_0 = colors[colorIndices[0]];
        var c0_1 = colors[colorIndices[1]];
        var c1_0 = colors[colorIndices[2]];
        var c1_1 = colors[colorIndices[3]];

        var istep = 1 - step;
        var r1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[0] + step * c0_1[0]);
        var g1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[1] + step * c0_1[1]);
        var b1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[2] + step * c0_1[2]);
        var color1 = "rgb("+r1+","+g1+","+b1+")";

        var r2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[0] + step * c1_1[0]);
        var g2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[1] + step * c1_1[1]);
        var b2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[2] + step * c1_1[2]);
        var color2 = "rgb("+r2+","+g2+","+b2+")";

        $('#gradient').css({
            background: "-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from("+color1+"), to("+color2+"))"}).css({
            background: "-moz-linear-gradient(left, "+color1+" 0%, "+color2+" 100%)"});

        step += gradientSpeed;
        if ( step >= 1 )
        {
            step %= 1;
            colorIndices[0] = colorIndices[1];
            colorIndices[2] = colorIndices[3];

 
            colorIndices[1] = ( colorIndices[1] + Math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * (colors.length - 1))) % colors.length;
            colorIndices[3] = ( colorIndices[3] + Math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * (colors.length - 1))) % colors.length;

        }
    }

    setInterval(updateGradient,10);
```

```css
#gradient{
  width:500px;
  height:400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="gradient"></div>
```

Comment: Супер спасибо !!!
А как задержку сделать нужно чтобы цвет каждые 30 сек менялся ?

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский [вот первоисточник](https://gist.github.com/tolu360/ddaa54842998fd54d5cbec5353821eee)  [Tolu Olowu](https://codepen.io/tolu360/pen/ObWrPO) 2016 год